# Media player in C# with text and images overlay

Tags: c#, media-player, media

I have just read some discussions about this topic but I didn't find the definitive answer.

Is possibile in C# do this:

1. Media player that read playlist and could run common video format (MP4)
2. Text and images overlay (I'd like to write and put images over a running video)

For example media player is running a playlist with more videos:

- Video 1 that last 9 seconds (I'd like to write text1 in a certain position for 9 seconds)
- Video 2 that last 6 seconds (I'd like to write text2 and punt image2 in a centain position for 6 seconds)
  etc.

Can I do this in C# & .NET?
Which technology/classes/components do I need for do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Video tutorial on WPF Video Player](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_bBWHCoKpk)
3. [XNA Video Player SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131439/xna-game-full-screen-animation-video-playback)
4. [Play Video on WinForms Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/53d1071b-26d9-406a-877c-3b33eedf8a4c/)

Not all options cover your requirements completely, and you will have to add functionality yourself too, but at least you have some leads.

I think in your case the WPF MediaElement might be most interesting to look at.

Good luck!